# Insert Null value in ADO Recordset

Tags: sql-server, vb6, sql-server-2000, ado, recordset

Is it possible to insert a null value into a field using the `AddNew` method of an ADO Recordset in VB6?  In a typcial `INSERT` query, you would simply use `NULL`; however, I've discovered that this doesn't work through ADO; it inserts "NULL" instead.

Is there another way to insert a null value when adding a new record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does leaving the value blank work?  Can you use dbnull.value?

Comment: Nope, it just inserts a blank string into the table.

Comment: Can you post your code?  Also, I'm assuming inserting nulls is supported on your table and you can insert your record with null values fine through the back end.

Comment: Turns out that the null value works if I leave that column out of the field and value lists in the `AddNew` method. Thanks for your help!